# Использование margin смещает объект в одну сторону

Tags: html, css

Имеется некий блок расположенный по центру, при прописывании 'margin: 0 50px', margin применяется к обеим сторонам, но при этом блок смещается вправо, а не остается на месте(как будто был задан только margin-left: 50px). При уменьшении размера экрана, действие margin-а применяется только к левой стороне(видно на картинке). В стилях ко всем элементам прописано:

```
*
    box-sizing: border-box
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
```

Стили блока(хотя проблема с margin-ом связана с любым элементом на странице):

```
    .block
        position: absolute
        top: 50%
        left: 50%
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        background-color: $white
        width: 100%
        max-width: 960px
        margin: 0 50px
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что margin + width > 100%. Используйте padding

Comment: @soledar10 но при использовании padding отступы задаются изнутри, а не внешние

Comment: У вас получается сейчас 50px + 50px  + 100% > 100%. Пример https://jsfiddle.net/053re8ta/

Comment: @soledar10 ок, понял, если в таком случае требуется использовать padding-и, то к какому элементу их применять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас так получается, потому что при суммировании ширины блока `width: 100%;` и отступов `margin: 0 50px;`, в общей сложности ширина получается: 100% + 100px.

В этом случае ширину блока следует указать так:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Таким образом вы отнимаете отступы `margin: 0 50px;`.

Про свойство `calc` можно почитать [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc).

Вот пример:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {background: lightgray;}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>Стихи Пушкина – это богатейшее культурное наследие, подаренное миру. Всю жизнь он занимался тем, что обращал чувства в строки. Александр Сергеевич был невероятно талантливым человеком. Диапазон тем, которые он отображал в стихах, поражает своей широтой. Добрые и глубокомысленные сказки для детей, саркастичные эпиграммы, нежные стихи о любви, о верной дружбе, веселье и вине, самоироничные строчки о себе и о своем творчестве.</p>
  <p>Не обошел стороной он и государственные события: писал о войне, о Родине, о России.</p>
</div>
```

Хотя, возможно, я не совсем верно понял задачу. Может быть нужно позиционировать блок таким образом?

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {background: lightgray;}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% - 50px), -50%);
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p>Стихи Пушкина – это богатейшее культурное наследие, подаренное миру. Всю жизнь он занимался тем, что обращал чувства в строки. Александр Сергеевич был невероятно талантливым человеком. Диапазон тем, которые он отображал в стихах, поражает своей широтой. Добрые и глубокомысленные сказки для детей, саркастичные эпиграммы, нежные стихи о любви, о верной дружбе, веселье и вине, самоироничные строчки о себе и о своем творчестве.</p>
  <p>Не обошел стороной он и государственные события: писал о войне, о Родине, о России.</p>
</div>
```